# Inversion in a circle in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, mobius-transformation

I'm self-studying a book about complex analysis and Riemann surface and would like to get some help with the following question.

### Background

On page 28 of [2], the authors have derived an equation for the inversion $I_C$ for a Euclidean circle C in $\mathbb{C}$ by employing the following definition of the inversion;

> Let p be the centre and r the radius of C (a circle in $\mathbb{C}$). For each $z \in \mathbb{C} - {p}$ there is a unique point w on the line through p and z such that $|z - p| \cdot |w - p| = r^2$.

Now, in the actual derivation, they started off with the following;

> We now derive an equation for $I_C$. If $z \neq p, \infty$ we have $|(\bar{z} - \bar{p}) (w - p)| = |z - p| \cdot |w - p| = r^2$, now arg(z - p) = arg(w - p), so $arg((\bar{z} - \bar{p})(w - p)) = 0$, and hence, $(\bar{z} - \bar{p})(w - p) = r^2$, ...

** Just in case, let me put the accompanying figure (Fig 2.3) from the book below;

[image]

### My questions

- Where does the term $(\bar{z} - \bar{p})$ come from?
- How can we deduce to get the relationship of $(\bar{z} - \bar{p})(w - p) = r^2$?

Thank you for your support!

### Reference

[2] Jones, Gareth A., and David Singerman. Complex functions: an algebraic and geometric viewpoint. Cambridge university press, 1987.

Comment: $\overline{z-p}$ is introduced so that the product later is real, it fits with the rest of the proof you have not shown, apparently. And for the second part, if the product has norm $r^2$ and argument $0$ then it equals the real number $r^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $\alpha = \arg(z - p) = \arg(w - p)$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
 r^2 &= |z-p| \cdot |w-p| \\
&= |z-p| e^{-i\alpha} \cdot |w-p| e^{i\alpha}\\
&= \overline{(z-p)} \cdot (w-p) \\
& = (\bar z - \bar p) \cdot (w-p) \, .
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! It makes sense till the 2nd line to me... I think I'm missing something pretty simple but why $|w−p| e^{i \alpha} = (w - p)$?

Comment: @Rowing0914: For any (nonzero) complex number $z$ is $z = |z| e^{i \arg z}$ and $\bar z = |z| e^{-i \arg z}$.

Comment: Sorry, I totally overlooked it... And I also just found the that relationship on Wiki, anyway, thank you!